# Give a proof for ...

Tags: coding-theory

My major is electrical engineering still undergraduate and I just enjoy learning math. I have started with a book of abstract algebra by Pinter. My question is
 In the remaining exercises, let $C$ be a code in, let $m$ denote the minimum distance in $C$, and let $a$
and $b$ denote codewords in $C$.

5)  Prove that it is possible to detect up to $m − 1$ errors.

a) how can I find the minimum distance between two codewords when $a$ and $b$ are unknown ?

**Note: The idea for me is clear, but still I cannot prove it mathematically.**

Comment: I don't know how concrete knowledge of the idea you have, but what is it in your idea that you don't think meet up with mathematical standards? At least for the 5) question I don't think there's any opportunity to get a substandard proof.

Comment: The idea is simple, for example if we have 000 and 101 then these two codes differ by two positions, so the distance between them is 2, but how can I get the distance if the codes are not known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the minimum distance of the code is $m$ it means that there are pairs of codewords that differ on $m$ positions. There might be just one such pair or many more. But there are no pairs of codewords that differ in *less* than $m$ positions. So $d(C)=\min\{d(a,b)|a,b \in C,a\neq b\}$

An $m-1$ error is equivalent to receiving a codeword $u$ that differs on exactly $m-1$ positions from a codeword $a\in C$. Why is this error detectable? Because if $u\in C$ then $d(u,a)=m-1$ and then, the code's distance, $d(C)$, would be equal to $d(C)=m-1\lt m$.

What is perceived as a problem of a sufficiently rigorous mathematical proof arises from the fact that we suppose that we have an algorithm, a mechanism if you like that checks every received word by comparing it with all the codewords in $C$. But that supposition has to be made.